# A variable from another function is getting updated somehow

Tags: python, list, function

I have a function that calls another function.  For some reason, the variable in the first function is updated by the second function.  Is python passing a variable by ref as a default?  Basically why is 'AA' updated in the second run? And how can I make it the same, just like the first run.

For simplicity, I created a short sample code that has the same issue.  I have a function (test) that calls (test2).  The variable 'AA' in 'test' is updated by 'test2' when I perform BB.append(list_position[0]).

The two function is below:

```
def test(A, childs):

    for x in range(0,childs):
        list_pos = [x]

        AA = A

        print("")
        print("AA: ", AA)
        print("list_position: ", list_pos)
        test2(origin,list_pos)

def test2(B,list_position):


    BB = B
    list_len = len(BB)

    print(list_position[0])
    #BB.append(list_position[0])
```

Output of the first run (with last code commented out):

```
AA:  []    
list_position:  [0]    
0

AA:  []    
list_position:  [1]    
1

AA:  []    
list_position:  [2]    
2

AA:  []    
list_position:  [3]    
3
```

Output of the Second run (with last code uncommented):

```
AA:  []    
list_position:  [0]    
0

AA:  [0]    
list_position:  [1]    
1

AA:  [0, 1]    
list_position:  [2]    
2

AA:  [0, 1, 2]    
list_position:  [3]    
3
```

Comment: test2(origin,list_pos) should be test2(AA,list_pos)

Comment: Also, please don't submit piece-meal code snippets like this which are incomplete. Instead, include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Okay, `AA = A` and `BB = B` don't really seem to do anything, since they just reference the parameter that was passed in

Comment: Yea it doesn't do anything, I was just trying to find out why updating BB changes AA.

Comment: Because `BB` *is* `AA`. `BB = B = AA = A`

Comment: Shouldn't 'A' be a different variable?   If not how can I keep that variable in 'test' unchanged, when updating BB

Comment: @user1179317 They're different variables, but both variables refer to the same list. See the duplicate question.

Comment: python use reference to the same place in memory instead of copy/clone/duplicate values and put it in new place - you have to copy/clone/duplicate values on your own - for example `BB = B[:]` or in Python3 `BB = B.copy()`

Comment: Jonathon, thanks.  It is a duplicate of that question.  I guess I didn't realize that's how python works, that it always reference to the same place in memory

Comment: The key thing to understand is *mutable* objects (sets, lists, dicts) vs *immutable* objects (strings, integers, tuples etc). If you can get your head around the difference you'll generally avoid this sort of confusion.